# VirtualBox Disk Encryption vs. Ubuntu VM Disk Encryption

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, performance, encryption

I am creating a VirtualBox VM that runs Ubuntu and  I would like to have the virtual disk encrypted.  Are there performance and/or security advantages to using the VirtualBox Disk Encryption over Ubuntu's LUKS disk encryption within the VM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand it, the good point of the VB encryption is that you can easily change your mind, encrypt a VM that isn't or decrypt a VM which is, and use the result with VB. Making a decrypted image from a LUKS-encrypted one and vice-versa is likely possible but would be more complicated.

Also, with the VB encryption you can store the encryption passphrase in the VB config outside of the VM, so you can boot the VM without having to enter a decryption passphrase. Of course you have to keep the VB config safe to avoid disclosure of the passphrase.

Comment: Thanks for the information!

Comment: Another benefit is that you can securely save the VM state to resume later. Encrypted VMs have their state file encrypted as well. In contrast, if using full-disk encryption features of the guest, **saving the VM state will effectively leak the encryption key to the host's storage in the state file.**

Comment: @cdhowie the [virtualbox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#diskencryption) says **the saved state is NOT encrypted** "The disk encryption feature can protect the content of the disks configured for a VM only. **It does not cover any other data related to a VM, including saved state** or the configuration file itself." Or am I misreading something?

Comment: @JessetheWindWanderer I wonder if this changed at some point then, because I'm pretty sure when I wrote that comment that the saved state was also encrypted. I don't think I would have claimed that without reading it in some documentation. The point remains, though, that when using guest-side disk encryption, a save state will leak the encryption key in the save state, but will not when using hypervisor-side encryption.

Comment: Thanks @cdhowie perhaps by "including saved state" the manual only means that the metadata of the saved state is not encrypted? I'm not sure how to test that myself. But thanks for the info and clarification that VB encryption is potentially more secure (depending on where you store the encryption key).

Comment: @JessetheWindWanderer It likely means all save state data, but I don't know how to verify this either.  Encrypting the save state could be problematic in some situations, for example when the VM has multiple disks encrypted with different keys -- what key is used for the state?